# Spell Checker notices error but doesn't highlight correctly

Tags: spellchecker

When I have a rich text box with no spelling mistakes and hit spell check it states "The spelling check is complete" in the popup dialog.

However if I add a mistake like the word "umpossible" this is what I get:
[image]

I imagine it should offer me the word "umpossible" underlined and give "change to" options.

Any ideas on where I should start?  I'm very new to Sharepoint development and this is one of my first bugs.